# What is the shortest way to compute the last 3 digits of $17^{256}$?

Tags: exponentiation

What is the shortest way to compute the last 3 digits of $17^{256}$ ?

My solution:
\begin{align}
17^{256} &=289^{128} \\
&=(290 - 1)^{128}\\
&=\binom{128}{0}290^{128} -  ... +\binom{128}{126}290^2 - \binom{128}{127}290 + \binom{128}{128}
\end{align}

Computed the last 3 terms whose last 3 digits gave the last 3 digits of $17^{256}$.

Is there any shorter method to do this(which requires much less computation) ?

Comment: @Balarka: We need to work $\mathrm{mod} 1000$, not $\mathrm{mod} 100$.

Comment: Right, I missed that.

Comment: With some script: 681.

Comment: @FelixMarin That's the correct answer

Comment: You can square $17$ eight times, each time reducing mod $1000$. But  I don't know whether this is faster than your method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your way seems to be the fastest for me

$$\binom{128}{128}=1\equiv1\mod{1000}$$

$$\binom{128}{127}=128\equiv28\pmod{100}$$
$$\implies  \binom{128}{127}290\equiv 28\cdot290\pmod{1000}\equiv120$$

$$\binom{128}{126}=\frac{128\cdot127}2\equiv8\pmod{10}$$
$$\implies \binom{128}{126}290^2\equiv 290^2\cdot8\pmod{1000}\equiv800 $$

Using $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot c\equiv b\cdot c\pmod {c\cdot m}$ where $a,b,c,m$ are integers

Comment: How have you written $128.290 \equiv 28.29 (\mod 1000)$.

Comment: @user2369284, thanks, rectified

Comment: How have you written $28.290 \equiv 120 (\mod 1000)$. Sorry for being so dumb but my number theory is very weak.

Comment: @user2369284, as $28\cdot29=(20+8)(20+9)=400+10(2\cdot8+2\cdot9)+8\cdot9\equiv10\cdot4+72\pmod{100}\equiv12$

Comment: It should be $10.34$ , not $10.4$

Comment: @user2369284, $$10\cdot34=340\equiv40\pmod{100},40=4\cdot10$$ right?

Comment: How did you do the $\mod 10$ one ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12171/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-user2369284)

Answer (score 5):

Use Euler's Totient Theorem and the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

We have that $ 17 \equiv 1 \mod 8 $ and hence $ 17^{256} \equiv 1 \mod 8 $ as well.

Because $ 17 $ is coprime to $ 125 $, we know that $ 17^{100} \equiv 1 \mod 125 $.

We are left to calculate $ 17^{56} \mod 125 $, which can be quickly be done by hand via the method of doubling: $$\begin{align*} 17^{2} &\equiv 39 &\mod 125 \\ 17^4 &\equiv 21 &\mod 125\\ 17^8 &\equiv 66 &\mod 125\\ 17^{16} &\equiv 106 &\mod 125\\ 17^{32} &\equiv 111 &\mod 125 \end{align*}$$

Hence, $ 17^{32 + 16 + 8} \equiv 111 \cdot 106 \cdot 66 \equiv 56 \mod 125 $.

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have that the list three digits are $ 681 $.

Comment: How have you written $17^{100} \equiv 1 \mod 125$

Comment: Euler's Totient Theorem says that for coprime $ a, b $, $ a^{\phi(b)} \equiv 1 \mod b $, where $ \phi $ is the totient function. In this case $, a = 17, b = 125, $ and $ \phi(b) = 125 \left(1 - \frac{1}{5}\right) = 100 $.

Comment: How have you done the doubling ?

Comment: Perhaps I should have called it squaring. I simply meant it is easiest to square the number and calculate the new modulus each time. Then you can just write the exponent of the original number in binary and multiply to get the residue.

Comment: If going by hand use $106\equiv -19$ and $111\equiv -14$ to reduce arithmetic. Also $-59$ is easier to square than $66$ unless you know two digit squares.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what "shorter" means, but $\phi(1000) = 400,$ so $17^{400} = 1,$ so $17^{200} = \pm 1,$ so you only need to compute $17^{56}.$ Since you don't know which one of $\pm 1$ to take, you have two possible answers, but to know which one is right, look at the **last** digit.

Comment: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(1000)=100$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee cute, but it is not obvious how to quickly compute this for an arbitary value of $1000.$

Comment: @Serkan very true.

Comment: @IgorRivin, just follow the definition of lambda. It's really useful for composite modulo

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $1000=125\cdot8$

$$17\equiv1\pmod8\implies 17^n\equiv1\pmod8$$

Now, $\phi(125)=100\implies 17^{256}\equiv17^{56}\pmod{125}$

Then apply [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)

Comment: What is $\phi$ here

Comment: Totient function, I believe.

Comment: @user2369284, yes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: What is the work of totient function

Comment: @user2369284, From the definition $$17^{100}\equiv1\pmod{125}\implies $$ what wrote in the Post