# Find the last two digits of $3^{45}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

I was wondering if there is a simpler way to find the last to digits of a power such as $3^{45}$.
I reduced it modulo 100 to get the answer, which is 43. But I was curious if there was a simpler, or more eloquent way to get this result.

Here's my method:

Using the fact that $3^4=81\equiv -19 \pmod{100}$ and $19^5=2,476,099\equiv -1 \pmod{100}$

$$
3^{45}\equiv 3(3^4)^{11}\equiv 3(-19)^{11}\equiv 3(-19)(19^5)^2\equiv 3(-19)(-1)^2 \equiv -57 \equiv 43 \pmod {100}
$$

I just felt like this was sort of a messy way to find out that the last two digits are 43.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657131/find-last-2-digits-of-999, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619810/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-compute-the-last-3-digits-of-17256, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362012/find-the-last-two-digits-of-781,   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390685/the-last-2-digits-of-7777 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607829/get-the-last-two-digits-of-16100-and-17100

Comment: Related: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, we need to find $\displaystyle 3^{45}\pmod{100}$

**Method** $\#1:$

Now,
$$3^{45}=3\cdot3^{44}=3(3^2)^{22}=3(10-1)^{22}=3(1-10)^{22}$$

Now, $$(1-10)^{22}\equiv1-10\cdot22\pmod{100}\equiv-19\equiv81$$

**Method** $\#2:$

As $(3,10)=1$

using Euler's [Totient Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html), $\displaystyle \phi(100)=40\implies 3^{40}\equiv1\pmod{100}$

or using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $\displaystyle \lambda(100)=20\implies 3^{20}\equiv1\pmod{100}$

In either case, $\displaystyle3^{45}\equiv3^5\pmod{100}$

Comment: That does simplify it much "prettier" than my method. I have just not been introduced to Euler's Totient Theorem or the Carmichael Function yet, although I assume we are building up to that soon. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @kayeomans, my pleasure. Added a few Related

Comment: @kayeomans One can do it even more simply - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 50\!:\ \color{#0a0}{3^{\large 5}\!\equiv -7}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{3^{\large 10}}\!\equiv 49\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\,\Rightarrow\,3^{\large 45}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{3^{\large 5}}(\color{#c00}{3^{\large 10}})^{\large 4}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{-7}(\color{#c00}{-1})^{\large 4}\!\equiv -7,\,$ so $\!\bmod 100\,$ either $\,3^{\large 45}\!\equiv -7\,$ or $\,50\!-\!7\equiv\color{#90f}{43}.\,$ It must be $\,\color{#90f}{43},\,$ by ${\rm mod}\ 4\!:\ 3^{\large 45}\!\equiv (-1)^{\large 45}\!\equiv -1\equiv\color{#90f}{ 43}.$

Answer (score 1):

A simple method: If you write down the first 24 powers of 3, keeping just the last 2 digits, you get

```
1   3   9   27
81  43  29  87
61  83  49  47
41  23  69  7
21  63  89  67
1   3   9   27
```

After a few powers you realize that you only need the last 2 digits of some power of 3 to get the last 2 digits of the next power.

There is a clear pattern that it *cycles* every 20th power (note that the last digit cycles every 4th power: 1-3-9-7...). Therefore the last two digits of $3^{45}$ are the same as for $3^{25}$ and for $3^5=243$, i.e. 43.

Answer (score 0):

The background impetus for what follows is the multiplicative group

[image]

contained in $\mathbb {Z} / \text{100} \mathbb {Z}$.

and we stand ready to write

$\quad 3^4  \equiv 81 \pmod{100}$

From the (cyclic) group table we know that $81^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.

So,

$\quad 3^{45} = (3^4)^{11} \times 3 \equiv 81^{11} \times 3 \equiv 81 \times 3 \equiv 43 \pmod{100}$