# Last two digits of $529^{10}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Trying to find out how to get the last two digits of $529^{10}$.

I'm having trouble finding a good mod to reduce the $529$ down. Thanks.

Comment: if you want the last two digits, take mod $100$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679842/find-the-last-two-digits-of-345 and the related ones

Answer (score 3):

If you want the last two digits, take mod $100$, and $(530-1)^{10}\equiv 1\bmod 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Using it mod 10 :

$$529^{10}=9^{10}=81^5=1\mod 10 $$

and mod 100 more brutally

$$529^{10}=29^{10}=41^5=81^2*41= 1 \mod 100 $$

Comment: Use `\equiv` for $\equiv$ (that is what you mean, right?)

Comment: Yes equality stand because i'm talking about equivalence classes