# Last 2 digits of $143^{101}$ in base 10.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Last 2 digits of $143^{101}$ in base 10.

I have to use Fermat's theorem or Euler's theorem but I dont know where can I started.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for a prime $p$

Comment: And thus wiki page has enough information about Euler's theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679842/find-the-last-two-digits-of-345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we need to find last two digits, we should divide by 100. Here is the full solution.

$$Find \space a^{x}  \space mod \space n$$
$$a=143,x=101,n=100$$
$$We \space also \space know \space a^{φ(n)} \equiv 1 \space (\bmod 100) \text { if n and a are co-prime}...$$
$$\text {and 100 and 143 are co-prime.}$$
$$φ(100)=φ(2^2⋅5^2)=2^1.(2-1)⋅5^1.(5-1) = 40 \text {, where 2 and 5 are prime.} $$
$$So, 143^{40} \equiv 1 (\bmod100)$$
$$So, 143^{101} \equiv 143^{40.2+21}\equiv(143^{40})^2.143^{21} \equiv 1^2.143^{21}\space (\bmod100) \space \text {  ...(A)}$$

From here, I will show two ways.

Option 1:
$$Now, 143^{21} = (13.11)^{21}$$
$$So,143^{21} \bmod100 \equiv (13^{21} \bmod 100).(11^{21}\bmod100)$$
$$13^3 \bmod 100 = -3, \text {as the number ends in 97}$$
$$13^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv (13^3 \bmod 100)^7 \bmod100$$
$$13^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv (-3)^7 \bmod100$$
$$13^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv -87 \bmod100$$
$$13^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv 13 \bmod100$$
$$\text{We also know } 11^{10} \bmod 100 = 1$$
$$\text {or you can find the same way I did for 13}.$$
$$11^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv [(11^{10} \bmod 100)^2.11^1] (\bmod100) \equiv 11 \bmod 100$$
$$\text {Let's go back to, } 143^{21} \bmod100 \equiv (13^{21} \bmod 100).(11^{21}\bmod100)$$
$$So, 143^{21} \bmod100 \equiv (13 \bmod 100).(11\bmod100)$$
$$So, 143^{101} \bmod100 \equiv 143^{21} \bmod100 \equiv 143 \bmod 100 = 43$$

Or from point A,

Option 2:
$$\text {We know, }(x+a)^n \bmod x \equiv a^n \bmod x$$
where x, a and n are positive integers.
$$So,(100+43)^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv 43^{21} \bmod 100$$
$$\text  {We know or can easily check that, } 43^4 \bmod 100 = 1$$
$$So,43^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv (43^4 \bmod 100)^5.43^1 (\bmod100)$$
$$So,43^{21} \bmod 100 \equiv (1^5.43^1) \bmod100 = 43.$$

Comment: thank u so much for your answer

Comment: I realize I have made a blunder in my proof. Apologies. Please reject the answer so I can delete it. I will send you the proof shortly.

Comment: Now it is correct and you can give me credit :) Apologies for the last time.

Comment: Thank you very much :) u are very kind,no need for an apology for the last time :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

This amounts to calculating $143^{101}\bmod 100$.

Now $143\equiv 43\bmod 100$ is coprime to $100$, so we can apply Euler's theorem. As $\varphi(100)=\varphi (2^2\cdot 5^2)=2\cdot(5\cdot4)=40$, you ultimately have calculate $43^{101\bmod 40}=43^{21}\bmod 100$.

Last, you can use  the fast exponentiation algorithm, which works with repeated squaring. On the other hand, the order of $43\bmod100$ is a divisor of $40$. Repeatedly squaring will show you this order is a power of $2$.

Comment: ı think solving with euler's theorem is more accurate thank u

Comment: But I use Euler's theorem, since I  calculate the exponent modulo $\varphi(100)$! I only added remarks to make the computation by hand easier.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Compute $143^{101} \bmod 4$ and $143^{101} \bmod 25$. These are easy because of Euler's theorem.

Comment: We cannot break up 100 into 4 and 25 to do this. mod 4 will give 3 and mod 25 will give 18.

Comment: @MathLover. Use the Chinese remainder theorem to combine those two solutions into $43$

Comment: Good point. Yes, that can also be done. But as 43^4 mod 100 = 1, I felt it was easier to just do that from the point of 43^21 mod 100.