# Find the last $2$ digits of $9^{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the last $2$ digits of $9^{100}$.

---

Well, I know that $9^{100}$ mod $4$ is $1$,but I do not know how to find $9^{100}$ mod $25$ hence I do not know how to find $9^{100}$ mod $100$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you calculated the last two digits of $9^n$ for a few $n$?  You should find a pattern.  A spreadsheet and copy down makes it easy.

Comment: Good idea, but is there a way to calculate $9^{100}$ mod $25$ directly?

Comment: What you find is that the  values are periodic, so you just need to find where you are in the period.  This would work equally well for $9^{10000}$.  If you want directly, [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%5E100) gives the answer as $01$.  What more do you want?  Have you tried anything? -1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the last two digits of $3^{45}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679842/find-the-last-two-digits-of-345)

Comment: By Euler's theorem, $9^{20}\equiv1\bmod25$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate  $9^{100}$ mod $25$.

Using the 'brute-force' mod $25$ technique (no calculator necessary),

$\quad 9^{100} = \bigr(\big({(9^2)}^2\big)^5\bigr)^5 \equiv \bigr(\big({6}^2\big)^5\bigr)^5 \equiv {(11^5)}^5 = {\bigr((11)^2(11)^2(11)\bigr)}^5  \equiv {\bigr((-4)(-4)(11)\bigr)}^5 =$

$\quad \quad  {\bigr((16)(11)\bigr)}^5 =  {176}^5 \equiv 1^5 \equiv 1$ mod $25$

Answer (score 12):

Hint:observe that $9^{100}={(10-1)}^{100}$

using binomial theorem this can be written in the form of $100k+1$