# What will be the last three digits of the number $17^{256}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

> What will be the last three digits of the number $17^{256}$?

This question really intrigued me. First I thought that binomial theorem would help. But miserably failed. The given answer is 681. Please help!

Comment: Hint: use [repeated squaring](https://algorithmist.com/wiki/Repeated_squaring) and take the result modulo $1000$ at every step.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619810/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-compute-the-last-3-digits-of-17256

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the shortest way to compute the last 3 digits of $17^{256}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619810/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-compute-the-last-3-digits-of-17256)

Comment: write the exponent as $3x+1$ or as $400-144$

Comment: In base $17$, answer is $000$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be easily done by binomial 
$$17^{256}=(289)^{128}=(290-1)^{128}$$
In the expansion all terms except last three are multiple of 1000. Hence last three digit are by last three digits of last 3 terms i.e
Last 3 digit of ${128 \choose 126} (290)^2-{128 \choose 127} (290)+{128 \choose 128}$
$$. $$
=Last three digits of above terms are $(800-120+1)$
$$=681$$

Comment: An answer using this method was linked above  7 minutes prior to your posting. Please check the comments before posting answers to help avoid duplication.