# What is the 10th last digit of $17^{256}$?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-theorem

> What is the 10th digit of $17^{256}$ ?

I know how to do simpler version of this question (like finding the last digit or last two digits ) by writing the number in the form of $10m + n$ and then expanding using binomial theorem , but this approach is either too lengthy to apply here or not meant for this question.
So could someone please help me solve this either by this approach in a doable way , or various different approaches are also highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619810/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-compute-the-last-3-digits-of-17256

Comment: Do you mean 10th _last_ digit? $17^{256}=988379827\color{red}0\ldots\color{red}9784263681$

Comment: Yes , edited, thanks

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee  that worked , thanks !

Comment: I think you are just meant to square eight times.  You can reduce $\bmod 10^{10}$ along the way, but you need $20$ decimal digits in the square.  My spreadsheet fails unless I make a high precision calculation.

Comment: yeah right , I think the question isn't doable in a  shorter way without a calculator , anyways I got the idea and different approaches , thanks !